# jQuery não usa o dataset do HTML5 no data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Ao modificar um determinado valor inicial do `data` do jQuery, notei que o valor do `dataset` não é modificado.

Daí elaborei o seguinte teste:

HTML:

```
<div data-value="initial value" id="div-test-1"></div>
<div data-value="initial value" id="div-test-2"></div>
```

jQuery:

Primeiro teste:

```
$(function(){

    var $div1 = $('#div-test-1')

    console.log($div1.data('value')); // intial value

    $div1.data('value', 'new value'); 

    console.log($div1.data('value')) // new value


    console.log($div1.prop('dataset').value); // initial value

 });
```

Segundo teste:

```
$(function(){

        var $div2 = $('#div-test-2');

        console.log($div2.data('value')) ;// intial value

        $div2.attr('data-value', 'new value');

        console.log($div2.data('value')); // initial value

        console.log($div2.prop('dataset').value); // new value


    });
```

Ou seja, para definições feita com `data()`, os valores foram alterados para o jQuery, mas não para o attributo `dataset`; e, quando alterados no `dataset`, não são retornadas pelo `data()` como esperado.

Existe também outra diferença: Podemos definir valores do tipo `Number`, `Array` e `Object` através do `data` do jQuery. Já o `dataset` NÃO faz isso.

Veja:

Exemplo com `dataset`:

```
$('body').get(0).dataset.element = {nome: "wallace"};

console.log($('body').get(0).dataset.element) // [object Object]
```

Exemplo com `data` do jQuery:

```
 $('body').data('element', {nome: 'wallace'});
 console.log($('body').data('element')); // {nome: 'wallace'}
```

- Baseando-se nesse exemplo, podemos afirmar que o jQuery NÃO usa o `dataset` do HTML5?
- E, se "sim" para a primeira pergunta, existe alguma razão específica dele fazer isso?
- É seguro usar o `dataset` em projetos em que eu não vou usar o jQuery?
- Porque eles se comportam diferentes no que diz respeito aos tipos retornados?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Baseando-se nesse exemplo, podemos afirmar que o jQuery NÃO usa o `dataset` do HTML5?

É, o jQuery **não usa** o `dataset`. Isso pode ser comprovado olhando o [código-fonte](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js) da biblioteca.

> existe alguma razão específica dele fazer isso?

Até onde eu sei, o motivo é histórico. Quando o jQuery implementou seu método `data`, o `dataset` ainda nem existia, ou pelo menos não era suficientemente implementado pelos browsers para valer a pena usá-lo. Ele faz exatamente o que é dito na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Armazena dados arbitrários associados aos elementos selecionados, ou retorna o valor para a chave passada no primeiro elemento entre os selecionados.

A verificação dos atributos `data-` do HTML5 é na verdade um *fallback*. Se um valor for definido com `.data()`, recuperá-lo com esse mesmo método nem olha para o atributo (nem para a propriedade `dataset` do elemento em questão).

Portanto, o objetivo do `.data()` não é o mesmo dos atributos `data-` – que, como você notou, só aceitam strings como valor. Só que o nome é o mesmo, e ainda por cima existe o *fallback* que já mencionei, e isso torna a situação bastante confusa.

Se o jQuery resolvesse mudar isso nesta altura do campeonato, e fazer seu `.data()` funcionar como o `dataset`, certamente causaria sérios problemas para quem atualizasse a biblioteca.

> É seguro usar o dataset em projetos em que eu não vou usar o jQuery?

Não vejo por que não seria. Aliás, acho seguro usar mesmo se estiver usando jQuery, contanto que saiba o que está fazendo.

> Porque eles se comportam diferentes no que diz respeito aos tipos retornados?

Como o `dataset` é feito para lidar com atributos do HTML, ele é pensado somente para valores do tipo string. Tanto que na especificação do HTML5 a interface que define o `dataset` chama-se [`DOMStringMap`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#domstringmap).

Já o jQuery usa um objeto comum para mapear elementos do DOM aos tais "dados arbitrários", e isso permite, pela própria natureza da linguagem, que se use qualquer tipo disponível nela.

Comment: Muito bem explicado

Comment: Bacana, eu achava que o `.data()` era só pra recuperar valores dos `data-attributes`, mas também nunca tinha pesquisado a respeito. :D