# Significados de atributos data-value, data-title, data-... em HTML

Tags: html

Tenho visto em vários código HTML marcações como: data-value, data-title, quase sempre são nomes de atributos de tags com o sufixo: data-, gostaria de saber o que significam e sem tem alguma recomendação de uso/vantagem de uso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

São atributos incluídos a partir do `HTML5`.

Basicamente são atributos utilizados para auxiliar o desenvolvedor em consultas dinâmicas na própria página sem ser necessário o acesso a um `servidor -> BD`.

Os dados já poderiam vir montados na própria página quando solicitados ao servidor, e caso alguma interação do usuário, são de fácil acesso via `JavaScript` ou `CSS`.

> The `data-*` attributes is used to store custom data private to the page
>   or application.
>
> The `data-*` attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data
>   attributes on all `HTML` elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's `JavaScript` to
>   create a more engaging user experience (without any `Ajax` calls or
>   server-side `database` queries).

---

> Os atributos `data-*` são usado para armazenar dados personalizados
>   privada para a página ou aplicativo.
>
> Os atributos `data-*` nós dão a capacidade de incorporar atributos de
>   dados personalizados em todos os elementos `HTML`.
>
> Os dados armazenados podem então, ser usados no `JavaScript` da página
>   para criar uma experiência mais agradável ao usuário (sem ser
>   necessário qualquer chamadas `Ajax` ou consultas do `BD` do
>   lado do servidor).

*Fonte: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)*

---

### EXEMPLO

```js
$(".teste").click(function() {
  pais = $(this).data("country");
    if(pais =="Brasil") {
      alert("Brasileiro!");
    }else{
      alert("Americano!");
    }
});
```

```css
.teste[data-country=Brasil] {
    color: yellow;
    background-color:green;
}

.teste[data-country=USA] {
    color: red;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="teste" data-name="Marcelo Bonifazio" data-city="São Paulo" data-state="SP"
data-country="Brasil" data-lang="pt-br">
  Clique-Aqui!
</li>
<li class="teste" data-name="Ricardo Henrique" data-city="Oklahoma City" data-state="Oklahoma" data-country="USA" data-lang="EN-en">
  Clique-Aqui!
</li>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @MarceloBonifazio

Answer (score 2):

Muito bem explicado pelo amigo @MarceloBonifazio.

Porém, apenas uma correção: O exemplo `Javascript` seria na verdade feito pela biblioteca `jQuery`.

Sem jQuery, a forma de se obter esses dados vindo do atributo `data` é feito através do objeto `dataset`, que vem "dentro" do elemento que é selecionado pelo javascript.

Veja:

HTML:

```
<div data-nome="Stackoverflow" id="teste"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#teste');
// obtém os dados
console.log(element.dataset.nome); // Stackoverflow
//define o dado
element.dataset.nome = 'SOPT';
```

Além disso, as formas com que o atributo `data` é tratado são diferentes, quando comparamos o seu uso entre `Javascript` puro e `jQuery`

Isso me causava confusão. Minha dúvida foi tirada  nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50349/jquery-n%C3%A3o-usa-o-dataset-do-html5-no-data) que realizei aqui no SOPT.

Veja um pequeno exemplo do código funcionando no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/41km7jse/1/)

Comment: Obrigado pelo complemento @WallaceMaxters