# Pegar background-color de outro elemento

Tags: css3

É chato ficar sempre alterando a cor de background de varios objetos, quero saber se tem como eu definir a cor de um objeto e depois so igualar a cor dos outros com a cor desse objeto, para ficar algo dinamico, alterar a cor de todos ao mesmo tempo sendo que no código so indico a cor em um. Exemplo, tenho uma div.teste defino sua cor como blue.. como faço outras divs e outras tag pegarem a mesma cor de div.teste sem ter que sair atribuindo blue para todos.

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma classe em todos esses elementos, seleciona-los com JavaScript e mudar o background-color de todos eles numa taca só, seria isso?

Comment: no caso é só no css mesmo, pq ainda não defini a cor final, não tem como aplicar sem ser em uma classe nova? assim como expliquei na pergunta.

Comment: Bem você pode começar a usar SASS ou LESS, que basicamente são linguagens pré-processadas de CSS, com elas você cria scripts que após rodar gera o CSS pronto, com isso você pode usar variáveis e outras coisas que existem, nas linguagens de programação.

Comment: Não tem como, as classes são estáticas, você não pode altera-las depois do carregamento da página. O único jeito seria utilizando JavaScript, alterando o estilo dos elementos através do atributo style.

Comment: @SK15 não entendo como SASS ou LESS poderia ajudar nesse caso, o CSS será gerado da mesma forma e ele quer alterar o background-color em tempo de execução.

Comment: @Zignd Porque nos SASS ou LESS posso escolher uma variável e nela colocar uma cor e com isso aplicar em todos meus elementos, assim quando eu trocar a cor todos meus elementos trocam a cor automaticamente, mas como disse se caso seja realmente em tempo de execução somente com JavaScript, a menos que use um compilador de SASS/LESS em tempo geral.

Comment: @SK15 pra mim a pergunta ficou um pouco confusa, então eu posso ter entendido errado o que ele deseja fazer.

Comment: @Ivcs Você pode criar uma variável no SASS e utilizando um map, altera a cor dinamicamente direto no Devtools do Chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando somente CSS, não vejo nenhuma solução fora as sugestões que deram nos comentários: Utilizar uma classe contendo as regras específicas que o elemento deve ter.

Mas acho que ainda assim não seria o que está buscando, não seria dinâmico, até porque CSS não possui eventos e você não conseguirá controlar o "change" em um elemento.

Então, eu utilizaria Javascript para obter a cor do elemento e atribuir aos outros. O controle de "quem é o elemento alvo?" e "quem são os elementos que serão afetados?" dá para fazer com [***data attributes***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50669/4808). Por exemplo:

```js
(function(){
  
  var backgroundColor = document.querySelector('[data-parent]').style.backgroundColor,      
      targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)
    targets[i].style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;  
  
})();
```

```html
<div data-parent style='background-color:blue'>Eu sou azul :)</div>

<hr>

<div data-target>Eu serei afetado.</div>
<div data-target>Eu também.</div>
<div>Eu não.</div>
<div data-target>Eu sim.</div>
```

#### Exemplo dinâmico

```js
(function(){
  
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){

    setRandomParentColor(); // Altera a cor do 'data-parent'
    
    setTargetsColors(getParentColor()); // Pega a cor do elemento e altera todos os 'data-target'
  });
  
  
  /**
   * Gera uma cor randomica e altera a cor de backgroundd
   * do elemento com atributo 'data-parent'.
   *
   * créditos - @ZPiDER: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365036/4056678
   */
  function setRandomParentColor(){
    var color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16); // cor "randomica"
    document.querySelector('[data-parent]').style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
  
  
  /**
   * Obtém a cor do elemento com atributo 'data-parent'.
   */
  function getParentColor(){
    return document.querySelector('[data-parent]').style.backgroundColor;
  }
  
  
  /**
   * Altera a cor de background de todos os elementos
   * com atributo 'data-target'.
   */
  function setTargetsColors(color){
    
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]'),
        len = targets.length;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
      targets[i].style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  
  setTargetsColors(getParentColor());
  
})();
```

```html
<div data-parent style='background-color:blue'>Eu sou azul :)</div>
<button>Mudar cor</button>

<hr>

<div data-target>Eu serei afetado.</div>
<div data-target>Eu também.</div>
<div>Eu não.</div>
<div data-target>Eu sim.</div>
<div>Eu também não.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar `background-color:inherit` defina o background-color para o elemento pai...e nos elementos filhos coloque essa propriedade para que eles herdem do elemento pai.
Você pode criar uma div com principal e colocar outras divs dentro, ex:

```html
<div id="principal" style="background-color:#CCC">
  
  
  
  
  <div id="div1" style="background-color:inherit">
    
    
    </div>
  
  
  
  
  <div id="div2" style="background-color:inherit">
    
    
    </div>
  
   
  
  
  </div>
```

No caso vc precisaria alterar apenas a div principal...pois as outras herdariam a propriedade, voce tambem pode fazer em css dessa forma:

```css
div[name=colorir]{

  background-color:#CCC;

}
```

Entao basta nomear as divs que deseja mudar o background com o nome colorir

Comment: Em nenhum momento ele disse que os elementos eram filhos uns dos outros.