# A partir de um checkbox selecionado, pegar o valor de um atributo data proximo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boa tarde,
eu tenho um checkbox selecionado (check = true)

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 space">
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" id="cat5" name="rd_categoriaRamal" value="cat5" checked>
    </span>
    <label class="form-control" for="cat5">Cat. 5</label>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span id="teste" class="fluigicon fluigicon-info-sign bs-docs-popover-hover" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="Ligações locais, celular e DDD." data-original-title="Popover title"><label class="form-control" for="cat5">Cat. 5</label></span></span>
</div>
</div>
```

e eu quero pegar o valor do data-content que está perto dele:

```
"data-content="Ligações locais, celular e DDD."
```

eu tentei com esse codigo aqui, porem sem sucesso:

```
var explicacaoCategoriaRamal    =   $('input[name=rd_categoriaRamal]:radio:checked').closest("span .fluigicon").data("content");
```

Alguem consegue me explicar porque não está dando certo? Tentei algumas variações disso sem sucesso.

Comment: Tenta assim `var explicacaoCategoriaRamal    =   $('input[name=rd_categoriaRamal]:radio:checked').closest("span .fluigicon").attr("data-content");`

Comment: Infelizmente, assim não funciona. Dá undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de subir no DOM até `.input-group-addon`, procurar o sibling `.input-group-addon` e depois procurar um descendente com `data-content`.

Poderia ser assim:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var data = $(this)
    .closest('.input-group-addon')
    .nextAll('.input-group-addon:first')
    .find('[data-content]')
    .data('content');
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 space">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat5" name="rd_categoriaRamal" value="cat5" checked>
    </span>
    <label class="form-control" for="cat5">Cat. 5</label>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span id="teste" class="fluigicon fluigicon-info-sign bs-docs-popover-hover" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="Ligações locais, celular e DDD." data-original-title="Popover title"><label class="form-control" for="cat5">Cat. 5</label></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi que ele queria pegar o valor dentro do atributo `data-content`, não? Com isso, sugiro a função `.attr('data-content')` do jQuery http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @leonardopessoa Usar `.data('content')` vai pegar o atributo `[data-content]`, como você pode ver aqui: https://api.jquery.com/data/.

Comment: @leonardopessoa como o AP escreveu `pegar o valor de um atributo` achei esta a melhor solução. Não sei de `.attr` será a melhor solução por causa [da maneira como o jQuery lê campos `data-`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50355/129)

Comment: Compreendido. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: Excelente resposta, funcionou aqui. Eu tentei fazer algo parecido com o children sem sucesso. Vlw pela resposta.