# $.fn.data - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Bom, eu tô batendo a cabeça nesse código, estou lendo um livro sobre jQuery, mas não consigo fazer este código funcionar, alguém pode dar uma dica de como resolvê-lo, e pra que funciona este método ($.fn.data).

```js
$('#minhaLista li').each(function(){
    var $li = $(this),
        $div = $li.find('div.content');
    $li.data('contentDiv', $div);
});
var $primeiroLi = $('minhaLista li:first');
$primeiroLi.data('contentDiv').html('new content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <ul id="minhaLista">
        <li>Primeiro item</li>
        <li>Segundo item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "minhaLista" ´é um ID, o correto não seria `var $primeiroLi = $('#minhaLista li:first');`?

Comment: bom, até ai deu certo, mas qual a relação do $.fn.html() como um setter no código, "new content" não deveria ter aparecido na lista?

Comment: Depois da ultima edição parece que o script esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: sim, consegui resolver. Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque como resposta e não na edição da pergunta. Reverti a edição da Pergunta, agora basta vc formular uma resposta explicando detalhadamente aonde falhou ;)

Comment: Relacionado: [jQuery não usa o dataset do HTML5 no data?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50349).

Answer (score 0):

A função `$.fn.data` serve pra você adicionar ou recuperar dados em geral do elemento em questão. É bastante usado por outras bibliotecas e plugins, como por exemplo o [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Para mais informações, você pode ver na documentação: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Já no seu código, além da falta do seletor com o `#` apontado pelo [@Ricardo Pontual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual), também falta dentro dos `<li>` um `div` com a classe `content`, que ele busca em `$li.find('div.content');` e atualmente não encontra, não colocando nada nos dados customizados do elemento.

Ajustei o script e seu HTML para ele ter um `div` com a classe necessária em ambos os itens da lista, assim você verá o script trabalhar.

```js
$('#minhaLista li').each(function(){
    var $li = $(this),
        $div = $li.find('div.content');
    $li.data('contentDiv', $div);
});
var $primeiroLi = $('#minhaLista li:first');
var $oDiv = $primeiroLi.data('contentDiv');
$oDiv.html('new content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
    <ul id="minhaLista">
        <li>Primeiro item <div class="content">div 1</div></li>
        <li>Segundo item <div class="content">div 2</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```